# How do I convert a 1-D index into a 2-D index

Tags: arrays, indexing

I have a 2-D array and I want to access its elements with a 1-D index.

the array length varies. `row` varies but `col` is always 8(`Array[varies, 8]`)

Looking at [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494974/convert-1d-array-index-to-2d-array-index) , it seems I can't access elements correctly.

This is how I want to access elements with one index:

```
0 = (0, 0)        8 = (1, 0)        16 = (2, 0)
1 = (0, 1)        9 = (1, 1)        17 = (2, 1)
2 = (0, 2)        10 = (1, 2)       18 = (2, 2)
3 = (0, 3)        11 = (1, 3)       19 = (2, 3)
4 = (0, 4)        12 = (1, 4)       20 = (2, 4)
5 = (0, 5)        13 = (1, 5)       21 = (2, 5)
6 = (0, 6)        14 = (1, 6)       22 = (2, 6)
7 = (0, 7)        15 = (1, 7)       23 = (2, 7)
```

In this example my array is `3x8`. According to the formula:

```
row = index % 8;
col = index / 3;
```

Say for index `13` it will be:

```
row = 13 % 8 = 5 >> correct
col = 13 / 3 = 4 >> incorrect
```

So what am i missing here?

Comment: The column number increases by 1 after every column, i.e. every 8 entries, so you need `col = index / 8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
col = index / 8
```

You should use the same divisor (in this case, 8) for both the mod and the div. That way, they are in synch.

In your example,

```
col = 13 / 8 = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The example 3x3 confused me.