# Numpy find index of largest number in Array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large 2-dimensional Numpy array which looks a bit like this, and I want to find the indexes of the highest number in the array.

```
[[0.09911875 0.087047   0.07395894 ... 0.10334793 0.10507131 0.10572167]
 [0.09951172 0.08808007 0.07559184 ... 0.0953996  0.09637988 0.09686002]
 [0.09908096 0.08856899 0.07680183 ... 0.08633772 0.08709209 0.08753099]
 ...
 [0.16518855 0.1658697  0.16564748 ... 0.16108064 0.15890269 0.15795946]
 [0.16250964 0.1616099  0.16255783 ... 0.15931444 0.15753458 0.15655452]
 [0.16211866 0.15905266 0.15936445 ... 0.15891747 0.15701842 0.15521818]]
```

So far, I've tried to use `numpy.where()` as that function returns a tuple of coordinates but I've only been able to receive an array of tuples, but I want one tuple, the coordinates of the highest number. I've also tried to use other Numpy methods like `np.amax`, `np.max`,  and `np.where` but to no success.

---

To further explain, if you had a small 2D array like this. The largest number is `9.99` and the indexes of the highest number will be (2,2).

```
[[2.18, 4.01, 3.49, 1.22]
 [2.34, 5.23, 5.11, 4.23]
 [1.23, 3.42, 9.99, 6.02]
 [2.08, 4.01, 3.49, 1.22]]
```

Comment: Have you tried `numpy.argmax()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `numpy.argmax` method combined with `numpy.unravel`:

Here's a minimal working example:

```
import numpy as np

# create random array
a = np.random.random((8, 8))

# find indexes of the maximum value in this array
np.unravel_index(a.argmax(), a.shape)
# > [4, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```py
(x.argmax() // x.shape[1], x.argmax() % x.shape[1])
```

> (2, 2)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to convert the index found by `np.argmax()` into your matrix indexes. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5494983/8250094) shows how to do that.

This is how you could do it.

```
import numpy as np


a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 7], [4, 5, 1]])

max_index = np.argmax(a)
tuple_result = (max_index // a.shape[0], max_index % a.shape[1])
print(tuple_result)
```

Answer (score -1):

If x is the array then you can try

```
np.where(x==np.max(x))
```

This will give you the i,j positions in the array.

Comment: The only problem is that it will be a tuple of `np.array`s. But still, very elegant.